# Disable Slack logs?

Tags: windows-10, logging, slack

Similar to [this (off-topic) question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47153515/3063273), I'm wondering how to disable Slack's logging.

Currently, `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Slack\logs` is taking 271 GB of disk space. Nearly all the files are `webapp-T1XC3J1LXXXXX.log` files.

Nothing under `Preferences` looks promising, except maybe `Preferences > Advanced > Disable Local Storage`. But that seems too drastic a measure to take. Also, a quick Google search didn't yield anything interesting.

I'm asking about Windows, but this isn't a Windows-specific problem (see my link above to another person asking about OSX).

Comment: I would run a periodic task to delete old logs and retain, say, the latest three log files, so that you still have recent diagnostic information if you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got a response from Slack support on the same issue. She said:

> Thanks for getting in touch, and I'm sorry for the concern generated
>   with this logs issue — this is a known bug. It was caused by a Slack
>   outage that we experienced a couple of weeks ago.
>
> We'd never seen anything like this before and so I can only apologise
>   that they suddenly started taking up so much space. We've got a bug
>   report filed to improve on this in the future. I can let you know once
>   we've implemented a fix if you like?
>
> In the meantime, if you go to the menu and select Help > Reset App
>   Data, you should see those files disappear. Please note, that this
>   will sign you out of your workspace, so you'll need to log back in.

I just settled for manually deleting the log files for now, and will wait for the fix.

Comment: I also settled for manually deleting the log files. Thanks for reaching out to Slack support!

Answer (score 3):

Recent Slack versions (I noticed the problem on 4.3+) on Linux (+ perhaps on other platforms) can use `-s, --silent` command line parameter to silence console output.

```
leho@papaya ~ $ [-] slack -v
4.3.2
leho@papaya ~ $ [-] slack --help

Options

  -h, --help                   Print this usage message                                                      
  -u, --startup                The app is being started via a Startup shortcut. Hide the window on Win32     
  -v, --version                Print the version.                                                            
  -x, --rxLogging              Enable more verbose logging                                                   
  -g, --logLevel string        Set the minimum log level, e.g., 'info', 'debug', etc.                        
  -r, --resourcePath string    Set the path to the Slack's source directory and enable dev-mode              
  -s, --silent                 Do not stream console output to stdout                                        
  -i, --integrationTestMode    Run the application in integration test mode, which enables use of a          
                               different user data folder
```